# Backup Minecraft server ubuntu server

Tags: backup, minecraft, automatic

I have a mc server running on ubuntu server 22.04 and I want to set it up to shutdown the mc server every 24 hours back up the entire server directory then restart the server, Would this be possible and if so how

Comment: Which file system are you using on your server? If you're using ZFS, there will be no need to shut down the server before backing up 

Comment: @matigo I'm not sure, I just did the basic install of ubuntu server using the [iso](https://ubuntu.com/download/server)